# the date class from the real time database is not filled in

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I can't fill in the date class from the database. I don't understand why it doesn't work, everything seems to be written correctly.
In the initUser function, the date of the User Model class is filled in, but if you write the USER variable to println, it will be empty. Below is the code of the MainActivity class, which has the initUser function

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var btn_settings: ImageButton
private lateinit var btn_add_friend: ImageButton
private lateinit var btn_search_main: ImageView
private lateinit var search_main: EditText
private lateinit var nickname_main: TextView
private lateinit var Id_main: TextView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    initFirebase()
    initUser()
    init()
    initFunc()
    
    btn_settings.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    btn_search_main.setOnClickListener {
        if (search_main.text.toString() == "Happy") {
            val intent = Intent(this, psh::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    
    nickname_main.text = USER.username
    Id_main.text = CURRENT_UID

    println(USER)
}

private fun initFunc() {
    if (AUTH.currentUser != null) {
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}


private fun init(){
    btn_settings = findViewById(R.id.btn_settings)
    btn_add_friend = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_friend)
    btn_search_main = findViewById(R.id.btn_search_main)
    search_main = findViewById(R.id.search_main)
    nickname_main = findViewById(R.id.nickname_main)
    Id_main = findViewById(R.id.Id_main)
}

private fun initUser(){
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_USERS).child(CURRENT_UID)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener{
                USER = it.getValue(UserModel()::class.java) ?:UserModel()
            })


}

fun initFirebase(){
    AUTH = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://ert-d167-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").reference
    USER = UserModel()
    CURRENT_UID = AUTH.currentUser?.uid.toString()
}
    }
    
class AppValueEventListener (val onSuccess:(DataSnapshot)->Unit) : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

}
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    onSuccess(snapshot)
}

}

data class UserModel(
        var id: String = "",
        var username: String = ""
)
```

If you insert the USER variable into print, it will be User Model(id=, username=)

[image]

The data in the database is

Comment: "If you insert the USER variable into print, it will be User Model(id=, username=)" Can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show how you do that? Please don't add any more separate snippets though, as it's hard to understand how they relate (and I have a feeling this may be relevant to your problem). Try to show the code in a single snippet, that we can copy/paste to get the same problem you have.

Comment: In addition, that last snippet looks like you have a copy/paste mistake in there with the `C` and `URRENT_UID`, so you might want to fix that as well.

Comment: I did everything in one code

Comment: Thanks. I don't see any code logging the user to match with your "If you insert the USER variable into print, it will be User Model(id=, username=)" though. Can you show us how you got that output?

Comment: There is a println in the code to check the filling of the variable. logkat outputs UserModel(id=, username=)

Comment: Don't tell us that you have the code in there, but edit your question to show the exact code and its output please. As said before, where this code is matters - and code is the mostly likely way we're likely to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank van Puffelen asked for, and please also responded with @.

Comment: Everything worked for me, it turns out I called the variable before it was filled in.